# I want to get the current date time every time I update or insert a row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `s_phone` in this table there is column `s_update`.

I want to get the current date time every time I update or insert into this table

`getdate()` or `systime()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` get the date time when insert only not when update

Comment: You haven't asked a question, and your subject and content disagree. The subject says "every time i update or insert", but the text says "when insert only not when update". Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15332472/edit) to actually *ask a question*, and when you do please decide which one of those you want to do.

Comment: first sorry for the misunderstanding but this part of my question -- getdate() or systime() or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -- i just want to say that i used this functions and it didn't work thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)
The trigger will be automatically run when insert/update happen in the table.

For example:

```
create table tbl1
(
    col1 int primary key,
    col2 datetime
)
go
create trigger trg01
on tbl1
for insert, update
as 
begin
   update tbl1 
   set col2 = GETDATE()
   where col1 in (select col1 from inserted)
end   
go
insert into tbl1(col1) values (1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing, first you said, *"..i want to get current date time **every time i update or insert** into this table.."* and on the last part of your question, you said, *".. get the date time **when insert only not when update**.."*

But give this a try, why not set a default value on the column, example:

```
CREATE TABLE Hello
(
    ID INT,
    DATE DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
)


INSERT INTO Hello (ID) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO Hello (ID) VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO Hello (ID) VALUES (3)
INSERT INTO Hello (ID) VALUES (4)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80a6b/1)

Comment: thanks for your answer but what i meant with the last part of my question is that i tried this  3 word  -- getdate() or systime() or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -- and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
getdate() or systime() or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

These will give you the current system date time. if you want on the insert, update event 
capture the date time use the trigger or yourself you can get the datetime and insert into required table.